# Clear All Enteries In My Table When Not Displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't know if this is possible but I have a page which has 2 questions on and 2 lots of radio buttons (Yes and No).

Only one of the 'Yes' radio buttons can be selected and this then pre-selects the 'No' radio button for the other question.  This is do using JavaScript and is working fine.

My issue is, is that if the user selects 'Yes' to a question and my hidden section is displayed and the user enters an entry and clicks the 'Add' button, this populates my table but if the user then selects 'No' to the 'Yes' question which re-hides my `<div>` (which is correct) but if they then selects 'Yes' to the other question, the section is re-displayed and the `<table>` still has the previous entry.  Is there a way to remove it upon selecting 'No'

**HTML code:**

```
Template template = new Template();
template.Nvc.Add("[!YesRadioButton]", Html.RadioButton("TransferISA_RadioButton", "Yes", ViewData["TransferISA_Yes"].Equals(true), new { id = "TranYes", onclick = "CheckRadioOptions(this,'TransferIsa_Cell','No');", onchange = "oneSelection()", title = "To select 'Yes', 'No' has to be selected for a Child Trust Fund transfer in." }).ToHtmlString());
template.Nvc.Add("[!NoRadioButton]", Html.RadioButton("TransferISA_RadioButton", "No", ViewData["TransferISA_No"].Equals(true), new { id = "TranNo", onclick = "CheckRadioOptions(this,'TransferIsa_Cell','No');", onchange = "oneSelection()" }).ToHtmlString());
template.Nvc.Add("[!TranErrorMsg]", (Html.ValidationMessage("TransferISA_RadioButton") != null) ? Html.ValidationMessage("TransferISA_RadioButton").ToHtmlString() : "");
template.HtmlTemplate = cmsText.Text;

if (app.IsChild)
{
    template.Nvc.Add("[!CTFYesRadioButton]", Html.RadioButton("CTF_RadioButton", "Yes", ViewData["CTF_Yes"].Equals(true), new { id = "CTFYes", onclick = "CheckRadioOptions(this,'TransferIsa_Cell','No');", onchange = "oneSelection()", title = "To select 'Yes', 'No' has to be selected for a Junior ISA transfer in." }).ToHtmlString());
    template.Nvc.Add("[!CTFNoRadioButton]", Html.RadioButton("CTF_RadioButton", "No", ViewData["CTF_No"].Equals(true), new { id = "CTFNo", onclick = "CheckRadioOptions(this,'TransferIsa_Cell','No');", onchange = "oneSelection()" }).ToHtmlString());
    template.Nvc.Add("[!CTFErrorMsg]", (Html.ValidationMessage("CTF_RadioButton") != null) ? Html.ValidationMessage("CTF_RadioButton").ToHtmlString() : "");
    template.HtmlTemplate = cmsText.Info_Text;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function CheckRadioOptions(obj, layers, showValue) {
        if (obj == document.getElementById("CTFYes"))
        {
            document.getElementById("Transfer").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("CTF").style.display = "block";
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("Transfer").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("CTF").style.display = "none";
        }
        if (obj != null) {
            var value = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) { if (obj[i].checked) { value = obj[i].value; } }
            if (value == "") { value = obj.value; }
            if (value == showValue) { HideLayers(layers); } else { ShowLayers(layers); }
        }
    }
function oneSelection() {
             if (document.getElementById("TranYes").checked == true) {
                 document.getElementById("CTFYes").disabled = true;
                 document.getElementById("CTFNo").checked = true;
             }
             if (document.getElementById("CTFYes").checked == true) {
                 document.getElementById("TranYes").disabled = true;
                 document.getElementById("TranNo").checked = true;
             }
             if (document.getElementById("TranNo").checked == true) {
                 document.getElementById("CTFYes").disabled = false;
             }
             if (document.getElementById("CTFNo").checked == true) {
                 document.getElementById("TranYes").disabled = false;
             }
         }
```

I haven't added my HTML for my hidden `<div>` as there is vast amounts of it but below is the full page with the hidden `<div>` displayed and the table populated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to add this in my code behind

app.Application.Products.IsaDetails.IsaTransfers.Clear();